# Reversed Backhand Slice Drop Shot

Tags: terminology, technique, badminton

I want to extend the number of strokes I can play in my badminton matches. Therefore I want practice a particular badminton stroke, called:

> reversed backhand slice drop shot

Can somebody tell me how to perform such a stroke and most preferably provide me some footage of such a stroke being performed in a real match situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular stroke is very difficult to perform, let alone to pronounce. Timing is of the essence and technical ability is there to follow. I found a few video's of two of the top players in current badminton.

### Lee Chong Wei

On the 17<sup>th</sup> of March 2009, Lee Chong Wei and Kenneth Jonassen were playing an exhibition match for the inauguration of a new badminton sports hall in the town of Pécs in Hungary. In the second game Lee Chong Wei (LCW) performs two times the stroke you want to learn:
[image]

- [2'33"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ur5YruyBHhI&t=2m33s)
- [7'00"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ur5YruyBHhI&t=7m0s)

On the YONEX ALL ENGLAND BADMINTON CHAMPIONSHIPS 8th of March 2014, against Son Wan Ho in the Semi Final:

- [13'41"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCTJEMLyffM&t=13m33s)

### Lin Dan

A training session in preparation of the Yonex All England 2011:
[image]

- [1'07"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZFhm47Obs8&t=1m7s)

### Essentials

I tried to capture the essentials into the drawing I created:

[image]

Like the reversed slice (cross) dropshot, the intention is to make your opponent think, you're hitting a clear or dropshot. With the reserved backhand slice drop shot, your opponent will think you're trying to hit a clear (as Jonassen thought twice). Key is to put in the same amount of energy (racket motion), as to hitting a clear, but at the end perform a reversed slice.